# TCP Reliable Service

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to understand the core difference between reliable service and unreliable service.
To me, unreliable is UDP, such as DNS query and reliable is basically any TCP segment.

But let's just assume that the transport layer does provide some unreliable service to the application layer and the network layer does provide a reliable service to the transport layer. Would it be definite that data from the application layer on one computer will reach the application layer on another computer, unharmed?

Answer (score 0):

> ... let's just assume that the transport layer does provide some unreliable service to the application layer and the network layer does provide a reliable service to the transport layer.

I'm not sure how you envision this. The transport layer does not add any unreliability, it at most tries to deal with the unreliability of the lower layers (network layer, physical layer ...), i.e. provide some kind of reliability on top of unreliable layers.

> Would it be definite that data from the application layer on one computer will reach the application layer on another computer, unharmed?

TCP and UDP do not even care about the application. TCP will consider the reliability job done once the data reach the socket buffer of the peer because then the ACK will be send. if the application crashes before reading the data or simply has never time reading the data does not matter for TCP. To achieve this this one would need to have to implement application level reliability mechanisms.

And of course TCP cannot guarantee that the data even reach the peer, it will only try its best. But if the TCP window is closed so that it cannot send data (because the remote socket buffer is full) or if the peer simply never ACKs a packet the sender will simply give up after a while. Note that the sending application is not really aware of this because a `send` on the socket will return successful if the data were successfully put into the socket buffer on the local system and says nothing if the data were received by the target.

Apart from that TCP only slightly protects the data. There is a checksum which can detect a few bit flips and discard the data as invalid but it will not be able to detect larger errors.